# React Native - How to access device back button for drawer navigation

Tags: android, react-native

I am use react-native 0.70.6, and use Drawer navigation `@react-navigation/drawer: "^6.5.6"` for the navigate.
When I press device back button i want to redirect previous menu(screen) but right now it's close the app.

When I use `navigation.goBack()` in my `about.js` file it's work properly but when i press device back button it's close the app.

Here is my code

In my `App.js` file

```
import MyDrawer from './sidemenubar';

<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Splash"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        orientation: 'portrait'
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="Sidemenubar" component={MyDrawer} /> //for custom drawer 
      <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
  <AlertDialog />
</View>
```

In my `sidemenubar.js` file

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
    
<Drawer.Navigator
    drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
    useLegacyImplementation={true}
    initialRouteName="Dashboard">
          <Drawer.Screen
            name="Dashboard"
            component={Dashboard}
          />
           <Drawer.Screen
            name="About"
            component={About}       
          />      
    </Drawer.Navigator>
```

How can i fix this issue Please help me...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [BackHandler](https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler) from react-native.

Just register the `hardwareBackPress` event on mounting the component and don't forget to remove it while onmounting:

```js
    componentWillMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.props.navigation.goBack());
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress',true);
    }
```

That should hopefully solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For functional component.

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

function handleBackButtonClick() {
    navigation.goBack();
    return true;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButtonClick);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButtonClick);
    };
  }, []);
```

You can try using **useBackHandler** hook.

```
import { useBackHandler } from '@react-native-community/hooks'

useBackHandler(() => {
  if (shouldBeHandledHere) {
    // handle it
    return true
  }
  // let the default thing happen
  return false
})
```

Let me know does this helps you or not.